# AM/PM Conversion For Date Time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I've a very basic requirement that I did earlier but for now unable to resolve it. I've a table in database that stores in and out time as the following format:

```
8/18/2019 8:00:00 AM
```

So what I want is to convert the above into the below format:

```
8/18/2019 8:00:00 PM
```

Nothing complex here, just to convert from `AM` to `PM`. I tried something like this but not getting the exact result:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(M.IN_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM') IN_TIME FROM Table m
WHERE M.DATE = '31-AUG-2019';
```

Anything that I missed here? Would appreciate if someone points out.

Comment: Your two examples have exactly the same format. What you want is not a format conversion, you want to add 12 hours (0.5 days).

Comment: Yes, exactly @William Robertson. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, dates are stored in the internal format so you can not change it using what you are doing. What you see in database is the dates converted into the string.(human readable format)

You can try the following to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRUNC(IN_TIME) + (12/24) > IN_TIME THEN
IN_TIME + (12/24) 
ELSE IN_TIME END
 AS IN_TIME_CONVERTED
FROM TABLE M
WHERE ....
```

This query will convert only dates before noon to equivalent in PM.

Cheers!!

Comment: Just great! Thanks. Could you specify a bit how this actually works `CASE WHEN TRUNC(IN_TIME) + (12/24) > IN_TIME`?

Comment: This will convert IN_TIME to starting of the day and adding 12/24 will make this time 12 noon of the day. Now condition will check if this time is before noon or after noon based on it, if before noon the  just add 12 hours so that it becomes PM.